# Xamarin Memory Leak Media Plugin C#

Tags: xamarin

I have this code using James' Xamarin Media Plugin

```
  MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            file.GetStream().CopyTo(ms);
            imageToUpload.Add(ms.ToArray());
            imgSourceList.Add(new ImageToSet { imageData = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(ms.ToArray())) });

            Counter++;

            if (!submitForm.IsEnabled) submitForm.IsEnabled = true;
            file.Dispose();
            ms.Dispose();
```

There seems to be a memory leak in the app because after a lot of photos have been taken its crashing, this is the only possible place it could be coming from, Is it because of this line??

```
imgSourceList.Add(new ImageToSet { imageData = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(ms.ToArray())) });
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are not releasing the memory for what you are reserving in `imageToUpload` and `imgSourceList` those two lists are what is "leaking".

Comment: Hi @Cheesebaron I missed out some code, On the Submit button call I run this after a data call so the lists are being cleared                                                   imageToUpload.Clear();
     imgSourceList.Clear();
     GC.Collect();

Comment: But up until you press the Submit button, you are filling up the memory with your images. So it is prone to crash before if you take enough pictures. You should instead save paths to the images.

Comment: Where will the images be stored if we have to store paths though? I can't store them on the phone because 100's of photos are taken a day on a 16GB iPhone. P.S I appreciate all the help your giving me here!

Comment: You store them until you upload them?

Comment: Yeah but in memory which Im trying to avoid, like i could save them to an album but then the photos would still exist in the album after.